# API for getting GCP Committed-use discounts and it's applied resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cost-management, gcp-compute-instance

Is there any GCP API or GCP Java Client methods for getting Committed-use discounts details and resources for which CUD's applied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no such GCP API or GCP Java Client methods for getting committed-use discounts details and resources. As this is a valid and most useful request to achieve this, you can fill a Feature Request in GCP **[IssueTracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)** to create this possibility.

You can refer to the below Google documentation for relevant info which might be helpful to you:

- [Spend-based committed use discounts](https://cloud.google.com/docs/cuds-spend-based)
- [Committed use discount recommender](https://cloud.google.com/docs/cuds-recommender)
- [Resource-based committed use discounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts)

Comment: I believe this answer is correct. Committed Use Discounts are a billing item. The billing API does not provide this information (at this time).

Comment: Didn't test it, but I found the following documentation for a REST endpoint on resource-based CUDs: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts#rest_4